# ETIMEDOUT when Lambda function insert data into RDS

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am using Lambda to insert data to RDS. I have ~1000 records. However, I receive the following error when I test the function. When I check the database, only some (~160) of the records are successfully inserted. I cannot find any useful information about this because I do successfully connect to the database.

I use node and basically, use Promise.map to handle async. I believe the problem is not from the code, it is a network issue, maybe something limits my query count. Can anyone give me some insights?

```
{
  "cause": {
    "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "syscall": "connect",
    "fatal": true
  },
  "isOperational": true,
  "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
  "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
  "syscall": "connect",
  "fatal": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to set timeout out in your database:

to view timeout:

```
show VARIABLES like '%timeout%'
```

set up:

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to close all db connections after your queries are done for the lambda to exit properly else it will always timeout.

Also, make sure you initiate the db connections inside the lambda handler. This will ensure that db connections are always created when a lambda function starts and you will never get any `Connection closed` issues when a lambda container is reused